# Categorizing data based on a column in Numbers 3.X

Tags: macos, mac, iwork-numbers

I have recently migrated to numbers 3.0.1 on my MAC. I am not seeing the option "Categorize by this column" anymore. Any idea how do we group the data in new numbers based on a column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this incredibly useful feature has been completely removed from Numbers 3.x, and Apple has made no mention of when or if it will return.

Comment: Ahhh... Sad! Hope it is reverted back soon.

Comment: I couldn't agree more - it's the single feature that makes me want to use Numbers instead of Excel.